# Pygame Internal States/Inheritance Comprehension

Tags: python, animation, pygame

This site has been wonderful, and I am happy to finally join and post a question. Hopefully this is within the realm of guidelines, as it is a bit odd.

I have been teaching myself python over the past few months, and I am very interested in my first major project being a sidescroller 2D game. I am going through this [blog by Martin Hus](http://paarsgames.nl/2013/07/29/animate-mario-using-pygame/). Here he experiments with animating Mario. I find his technique very clean, and I am mulling over this trying to comprehend. I understand how spritesheets work, my question is more around how exactly the inheritence works with the "state.py" file.(you will quickly see he provides his own brief description, however this is still not clear to me).

From what i can see in mario.py he changes the class which is called based on the internal state. Is this what state.py is working off of?

from mario.py

```
self.jumping_state = jumping.Jumping(self)
```

from state.py

```
def jump(self):
    self.mario.state = self.mario.jumping_state
    return self.mario.state.jump()
```

Does the return then become jumping.Jumping.jump()? Which then executes the appropriate action/animation?

If this is the case, how does the syntax point to mario.py? I am left to say that it is all through the importing of the class that imports state.py (i.e Jumping, Standing, Walking etc..)

Or put another way:
state.py --> running.py (or whatever class it may be) --> mario.py

So in state.py the internal state is changed, which then jumps to mario.py and directs it to the appropriate, specific class name?

Comment: `states` are useful but hard to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

> Does the return then become jumping.Jumping.jump()? Which then executes the appropriate action/animation?

`self.mario.state.jump()` is a (method) function call statement. `self.mario.state.jump()` is invoked and the return value is returned from `jump`.